# Is it possible to have network-attached monitors?

Tags: networking, multiple-monitors, streaming

I'm a recently graduated EE trying to learn IT infrastructure stuff that wasn't even glancingly taught during undergrad, so apologies in advance if this question is silly. I'm concepting ideas for a project, part of which is displaying noninteractive content from a streaming server (text and video frames; think like a news channel) on largish screens that are far apart. I would like to accomplish this over ethernet since the infrastructure is already in place and it avoids having to rip things up to do video cable pulls. Is there such thing as a "network attached monitor" that is purpose built for this task, or would I have to attach thin clients a la Raspberry Pi to each display? Each monitor will be displaying the same thing simultaneously. Ultimately I would like to be able to point the screens to an IP address and display the webpage there.

I would greatly appreciate anything that points me in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: Some smart TVs can already do what you wanted (over ethernet). If your content are on web pages, then most Smart TV often has a browser built in and may be able to do what you want. Having a PC / Raspberry Pi / Mac Mini to run those TV would be better as you can run custom code, or content that may report back to your central server and display things accordingly. This is what Digital Signage that you often see on the mall with the touch-screen interaction. You can re-use that same concept with non-interactive display of course. There will be lots of companies offering digital sign product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there such thing as a "network attached monitor" that is purpose built for this task, or would I have to attach thin clients a la Raspberry Pi to each display?

From a technical point of view, there is no difference between these two versions. There has to be a network device in the concept that is able to decode some protocol and drive the display with the data received. This device will 99% be some kind of computing device, with some processor, memory, and graphics output peripheral. Whether you buy it separately, or built into your display, does not matter too much technically. It does matter pricewise (a separate product may or may not be cheaper), and flexibility-wise (a separate device can be easily replaced). If the device runs some standard OS, you'll have even more flexibility regarding the software to run there.

Both thin clients (see for example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun_Ray) and TVs with built-in net client computers have been available for many-many years.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is the type of thing you're looking for. It allows you to connect a single box to a display or projector, and then extend or clone a display from any computer on the connected network.

http://ca.startech.com/AV/Extenders/HDMI/HDMI-over-IP-Extender-with-Audio~IPUSB2HD2